# Blank lines not served in static, non-HTML files

Tags: apache-2.2, http

I am serving a non-HTML text file though Apache (2.2.22) on linux.

If I have a file like this:

```
Blah Blah
Blah

BLAH BLAH
```

...the empty (3rd) line get removed when it is served. If I put it inside a <pre> tag, like this:

```
<pre>
Blah Blah
Blah

BLAH BLAH
</pre>
```

...then it gets served correctly, with the empty line being NOT removed, as I would expect.

Is there any reason I am missing for this behavior, and any way to prevent the blank line from being removed without breaking too many things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blank line is being removed because the file is being served as HTML instead of plain text.  To fix this, if your text file has a distinct file extension, then set that extension to `text/plain` in your apache config dir `mime.conf` file.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the blank like is being ***REMOVED***? I bet you real currency that it isn't, and if you use your browser's "View Page Source" option (or retrieve the file with wget and look at it in a text editor) the blank line will be there.

Your ***browser***, absent more specific instructions is not ***rendering*** the blank line, because it defaults to treating everything as HTML. That's not a server problem though.

Comment: It is actually being **REMOVED**, yes. I am using curl.

Comment: @St0rM Wow - I've literally ***never*** seen Apache do that. Do you have some "optimization" or "acceleration" modules in your configuration? (Also I owe you real currency - would you like a rupee or a ruble? :)